# How to sort a list of dictionary with recurring specific order in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

My list:

```py
old_list = [
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '1.0'}, 
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '3.0'}, 
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '12.0'}, 
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '10.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '11.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '2.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '3.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '10.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '1.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '2.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '11.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '12.0'},
]
```

I want to sort them by the `date` and then the `hour` in such order (10PM - 3AM of the same day):
**Note:** It needs to be in that exact order as the example below

```py
old_list = [
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '10.0'}, 
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '11.0'}, 
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '12.0'}, 
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '1.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '2.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '3.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '10.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '11.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '12.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '1.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '2.0'},
    {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '3.0'},
]
```

How is this possible?

**Additional Information**
Use case of this is that I have a 24-hour range data of a few dates. I want to sort them by `date` and sort them from `6AM - 5AM` manner.

Comment: In your expected output, you put the `'hour': '1.0'` dicts after the `'hour': '12.0'`. Why? How do you know to do that? what actually is the rule for comparing these values?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes that is correct, it's what my client requested.

Comment: Given one of the items, could you write code that tells you how many hours that entry is after the start of the day? Could you write code that tells you how many days it is after some specified start time? If you had those pieces, would you know how to sort the list using `sort`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, one way using `modulo` to reflect the shifted timeline:

```
sorted(old_list, key=lambda x: (x["date"], (float(x["hour"]) - 6)%24))
```

Output:

```
[{'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '10.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '11.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '12.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '1.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '2.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-12', 'hour': '3.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '10.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '11.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '12.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '1.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '2.0'},
 {'date': '2021-11-13', 'hour': '3.0'}]
```

Insight:

- `(float(x["hour"]) - 6) % 24`: Shifts your distribution of time (a.k.a. 6AM - 5AM) by 6 hours (i.e. usual 24 hour). Then the shifted hours are rebounded into 24 hour boundary.

Thus the hours in the original data are transformed into:

```
1.0 --> 19
3.0 --> 21
12.0 --> 6
10.0 --> 4
11.0 --> 5
2.0 --> 20
3.0 --> 21
10.0 --> 4
1.0 --> 19
2.0 --> 20
11.0 --> 5
12.0 --> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If time complexity doesn't matter (unless hour_order has only few elements everything will be fine), here it is:

```
from datetime import datetime

hour_order = ["10.0", "11.0", "12.0", ...]
sorted(
    old_list,
    key=lambda d: (datetime.strptime(d["date"], "%Y-%m-%d").date(), hour_order.index(d["hour"])),
)
```